# How to use 64BIT UNSIGNED LONG LONG TYPE in javascript

Tags: javascript

In c++:

```
4* 11400714819323198485llu==8709371129873690708
```

How to get same result in javascript , thanks

Comment: A bit more specific?

Comment: long answer, you can't, short answer, yet

Comment: hi Prashant Pimpale,In javascript not have 64BIT UNSIGNED LONG LONG TYPE, i want to know how to get same result with out llu prefix , or some thing can replace 64BIT UNSIGNED LONG LONG TYPE number in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Can't. For now use a bignum package [like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bignumber.js).

Answer (score 0):

Try BigInt. https://caniuse.com/#search=bigint

```
4n * 11400714819323198485n =
45602859277292793940n
```